# Syntax Error: XPath Is Not a Legal Expression

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

How can I find a syntax error within a complicated XPath expressions when all I'm told is:

> **Syntax Error:** Given XPath expression `//td[text()="ASIN"] || //li[contains(., "ASIN: ")]` is not a legal expression.

I would really like to know

- How can I fix this problem?
- How can I fix other XPath syntax problems (without having ask here each time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lousy diagnostic message.

### Your particular XPath syntax problem

Rather than `||`, which is logical OR in some languages, you're probably looking for `|`, which is [nodeset union in XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-sets).  (That is, assuming you're not aiming for XPath 3.0's [string concatenation operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-concat).)

## How to find and fix XPath syntax problems in general

1. **Use a better tool.**  Diagnostic messages are hard to write well.  While it is not possible in the general case to always specify exactly what to fix to repair a syntax error, the best tools help the most.  If your tool says no more than *`XPath syntax error`*, you can definitely learn more by attempting to evaluate your XPath using a better tool:

   - [oXygen XML Editor](https://www.oxygenxml.com/) using [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/products.html):

     > XPath failed due to: Concatenation operator ('||') requires XPath 3.0 to be enabled
   - http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

     > err:XPST0003: This language feature is not available in the selected language. At least XQuery/XPath version 3.0 is required 
     >   in: //td[text()="ASIN"] || [<- error occurs before here]  //li[contains(., "ASIN: ")]
   - [www.xpathtester.com/xpath](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath):

     > ERROR - Failed to evaluate XPath expression: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location path was expected, but the following token was encountered: |
2. **Avoid common XPath version<sup>1</sup> requirement mistakes:**

   1. [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)
   2. [XPath 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) is needed for regex, sequences.
   3. [XPath 3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/) is needed for namespace literals, ||, !, inline anonymous functions.
   4. [XPath 3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/) is needed for array and associative arrays.
3. **Use the (BNF) force, Luke**: The above XPath versions link to the associated W3C XPath Recommendations, which include the definitive grammar rules that define legal XPath syntax.  Know these well to spot/avoid XPath syntax errors.

<sub><sup>1</sup>     XPath unfortunately has no built-in way to elicit its version.  That
   leaves two options: (1) know the version that the hosting language,
   library, or application implements based upon its documentation, or (2) initiate a simple probe (of known
   proper syntax, of course) that uses a version-specific feature and see if a syntactical is avoided.</sub>

Comment: There generally is no single, unique XPath to select any given element in an XML document.

Comment: Other than preserving the sets before the union or re-testing after the union, no.

Comment: I have a better idea.  When I get some time, I'll re-write your question to add long-term value to the site.  If you're patient, I believe I can turn your -6 into a positive number, perhaps even significantly positive.  Sound good?

Comment: Answer updated with note regarding versioning determination.